# Reactive subscription depending on current time in Meteor

Tags: meteor, publish-subscribe

In an application that allows realtime chat between clients, I aim to integrate functionality that allows to define messages that are delivered at future points in time.

In the following example, I am able to insert messages, which are inserted directly into the template. However, I would like to display only messages that have a time smaller or equal to the current time, but automatically display messages that have future time points as soon as the time is reached. For example, if I insert a message from the console, which should be displayed 30 seconds in the future by calling `Meteor.call("createMessage", 30000, "hello in 30 seconds")`, the message should be automatically displayed after 30 seconds.

I started restricting the query in the publish function to `time: {'$lt': new Date()}`. However, I have trouble in making this reactive. I unsuccessfully tried several combinations of `Tracker.autorun` and `cursor.observe`.

Can anybody give me a hint how I accomplish the desired reactivity within the following running example?

1) html file

```
<body>
    {{> chat}}
</body>

<template name="chat">
 {{#each chatMessages}}
    {{time}} - {{message}} <br>
 {{/each}}
</template>
```

2) js file

```
//server and client 
Messages = new Mongo.Collection("messages"); //{time: Sun Nov 02 2014 22:17:32 GMT+0100 (CET), message: "hello"}

//server
if(Meteor.isServer){
  Meteor.methods({
    'createMessage': function(timeOffset, message){
      Messages.insert({
        time: new Date(new Date().getTime() + timeOffset),
        message: message
      });
    }
  });

  Meteor.publish("messages", function(){
    return Messages.find({
      //time: {'$lt': new Date()}
    });
  });
}

//client
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.chat.helpers({
    chatMessages: function(){
      return Messages.find({});
    }
  });

  Tracker.autorun(function (){
    mySub = Meteor.subscribe('messages');
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Date() was a reactive datasource, it would work but it's not.

You can create a Timer at server side that will handle it. The best design I see id: pick the next message future date and set a Timer with the time difference and also get the next message time. Of course it's dependes on how your application works.

Read more about Timers in Meteor: https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/timers

Comment: Thanks! So it is not possibel to make the result of a query reactive if date() is involved? At the moment I am having a counter on the Messages collection in Tracker.autorun. That works fine, but whenever my query involves date() (e.g. counting only documents that are less than current date), it does not work. This is because date() is not reactive itself if I understand correctly?

Comment: True. Keep in mind that the date approach might harm your server performance, I suggest you find a better approach to this. If you've messages that are very close, in time, to each other the result is: a batch of database queries and timers firing. Consider doing some caching in your application. Some Meteor Developers can't stop think about the reactive but sometimes adding the flag { reactive:false } makes no difference in some scenarios. How about getting the next 50 messages to cache and when it's empty you fetch the database?

Answer (score 1):

Reactivity means that the view reflects the data sources used to make that view, updates when those sources change, and only then (as a rule of thumb).

Therefore, if we want to accomplish what is described using reactivity, we must introduce a reactive change when the message goes live (the outlined model does not have such a change).

Two ways to accomplish this that I can think of:

- Add an 'isLive' field to the message, and have the server change it at the right time, using timed callbacks and `Meteor.startup` (to avoid losing messages in case of a reboot). Somewhat complex, but clean and performant (when properly implemented).
- Add a currentDate `Session` variable and use `Meteor.setInterval` etc. on the client, to keep it as current as you need (Because Session variables are reactive).

In the second alternative, the user could just change their system clock or use the javascript console to access future messages. Also, reactive events with a set interval seem rather contrived, unless that interval is significant to the problem domain itself (like a calendar app changing the 'today' session variable used to draw the red circle, every midnight).

A simpler (better?) non-reactive solution might be to simply render the future messages as hidden elements, and use javascript timers to show them at the right time. But it all depends on what you are dealing with of course.

Comment: I'm making a game with Meteor and I can vouch for the client-side use of a Session variable with the current time, updated in a "setInterval" function:
`Session.set("REACTIVE_TIME_VAR", new Date())`

It's very convenient for events with live-updating countdown timers or anything that needs to update with the passage of time (and not just updates to underlying data sources).  In my particular case, I only need an update every second, so it doesn't bog down client-side performance noticeably.  Best of all, it only required me to change two lines of my existing code.  Thanks for this suggestion!